# Vue 3 and vue3-openlayers - show all names of poin on clicked clouster

Tags: vuejs3, openlayers

I use Vue 3 and vue3-openlayers. I want to display all the names of points currently present in a cluster. When the cluster is clicked, the names of the individual points should appear, based on the cluster's size.

For example:

Cluster "3" should display 3 times the name of projects.
Cluster "1" should display 1 times the name of project.

i have small code

template

```
<ol-animated-clusterlayer :animationDuration="500" :distance="40" title="CLUSTER"
            preview="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MelihAltintas/vue3-openlayers/main/src/assets/cluster.png">
            <ol-source-vector ref="vectorsource">
              <ol-feature v-for="index in mapCover" :key="index">
                <ol-geom-point :coordinates="[
                  index.lon, index.lat
                ]"></ol-geom-point>
              </ol-feature>
            </ol-source-vector>

        <ol-style :overrideStyleFunction="overrideStyleFunction">
          <ol-style-stroke color="red" :width="2"></ol-style-stroke>
          <ol-style-fill color="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)"></ol-style-fill>

          <ol-style-circle :radius="20">
            <ol-style-stroke color="black" :width="15" :lineDash="[]" lineCap="butt"></ol-style-stroke>
            <ol-style-fill color="black"></ol-style-fill>
          </ol-style-circle>

          <ol-style-text>
            <ol-style-fill color="white"></ol-style-fill>
          </ol-style-text>
        </ol-style>
      </ol-animated-clusterlayer>

      <ol-overlay :position="selectedCityPosition" v-if="selectedCityName != '' && !drawEnable">
        <template v-slot="slotProps">
          <div class="overlay-content" >


          <div v-for="skill in selectedCityName" v-bind:key="skill[0]">
            <span v-if="content" class="badge bg-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
              :data-bs-target="`#staticBackdrop${skill[0]}`" style="margin: 3px;">
              {{ skill[1] }}
            </span>
          </div>
      
          </div>
        </template>
      </ol-overlay>
```

and some js

```
featureSelected(event) {

  this.selectedCityName = []
  if (event.selected.length == 1) {
    const extent = getCenter(event.selected[0].getGeometry().getExtent());
    this.selectedCityPosition = extent;
   
    for (let item in this.mapCover) {
      console.log(event.selected[0].values_.geometry)
      if (event.selected[0].values_.geometry.flatCoordinates.includes(this.mapCover[item].lon, ",", this.mapCover[item].lat))
    {
        const name = this.mapCover[item].name;
        const id = this.mapCover[item].id;
        this.selectedCityName.push([id, name])
      }
    }
  } 
},
```

but this code clicked on cluster "1" showing this project name, but when i click on for example clouster "3" nothing happens.

json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "idproj": [
            {
                "uuid": "0640c688-3828-43d1-8835-f8d08def59d3",
                "lat": "51.4168327",
                "lon": "15.8986889",            
            }
        ],
        "name": "Projektów 1”,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "idproj": [
            {
                "uuid": "c3b9e68c-ae2c-4eab-a0aa-28c9e1efc3b6",
                "lat": "51.2081617",
                "lon": "16.1603187",
         
            }
        ],
        "name": "Projekt 2",
        
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "idproj": [
            {
                "uuid": "d7bada02-42b3-4f4e-b71a-54d9d1712e69",
                "lat": "51.1089776",
                "lon": "17.0326689",

            }
        ],
        "name": "Projekt 3",

    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "idproj": [
            {
                "uuid": "0640c688-3828-43d1-8835-f8d08def59d3",
                "lat": "51.4168327",
                "lon": "15.8986889",
                
            }
        ],
        "name": "Projekt 4",
        
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "idproj": [
            {
                "uuid": "d481881d-ea37-442c-af68-dbc8f71f234e",
                "lat": "51.4168327",
                "lon": "15.8986889",

            }
        ],
        "name": "Projekt 5",

    }
]
```

Comment: easier, how to get the coordinates of points from a cluster?

Comment: Clusters contain an array of the features included in the cluster, you can get the properties of each of those features https://codesandbox.io/s/cluster-cities-jmvgmw?file=/main.js